# Changing protocol type from https to http in google webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console

I have a website for two year & in last year change its protocol to https. now my ssl certification is expired & I want to go back to http protocol. I add my http version to google webmaster tools but i don't know how to change protocol with No SEO loss, now both http & https exists in google webmaster tools.
in addition i did 301 redirect to http.

Comment: You can't 301 redirect away from HTTPS without a certificate.    When connecting to your old HTTPS URLs clients will get a certificate error before seeing the redirect.  Once you have HTTPS, there is really no going back.

Comment: "now my ssl certification is expired & I want to go back to http protocol." Why? You can just renew your certificate, including for free with some CA. Going back to HTTP is not a good idea, besides suspicion that it could raise from your visitors, browsers are more and more labeling/intent to label HTTP as "unsecure" so websites without HTTPS version will more and more become second grade citizens on the web...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I know that is not a good idea to back http protocol for SEO, but anyway someone maybe can not access ssl certificatatin.

Comment: "I know that is not a good idea to back http protocol for SEO," That is not the point, or at least not the one I want to do. It is not a good idea to go back to HTTP, for many reasons not just "SEO". In fact SEO is really the last important point there. Just note that browsers are on the path to label all HTTP as "unsecure". How will your visitors appreciate that? Don't try to go around the problem (certificate expired) just fix the real problem (renew the certificate).